# Executing another PHP file and return the output from a method, is that possible?

Tags: php, execute

Suppose if I have a PHP script test.php which have a method

```
<?php
function execute($filename){
    //do something

    return $output;
}
?>
```

and I also have another PHP script `executable.php`

```
<?php 
    echo "I am executed";
?>
```

then can i run any code to excute the second file and return the output from the first method `execute` when i call `echo execute('executable.php');` ?

I guess you guys can understand what I meant.

Comment: You can use output buffering, but this kind of coding has an awful smell to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [output buffering](http://php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php), as long as the file being included doesn't already do that:

```
ob_start();

require $filename;

$content = ob_get_contents();

ob_end_clean();

return $content;
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. Let me try that and i'll tell you :)

Comment: Can I use any local variables defined inside the function  in the executable.php file?

Comment: and what is I want to give the require file parameter ?    e.g. require $filename?p=1;

Comment: @njoshsn: `require` isn’t some kind of HTTP redirect. You can just set `$_GET['p']`.

Comment: thanks @minitech I ended up using RabbitMQ to pass data between scripts www.rabbitmq.com

Answer (score 4):

Use `ob_Start` and `ob_get_contents` to capture the output of the script. Something like this should work:

```
<?php

function execute($filename){
    ob_start();
    include $filename;
    $output = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    return $output;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php#test.php
    include 'executable.php';
    echo $test;
?>

<?php#executable.php
    $test = "I am executed";
?>
```

Comment: Second file will be just a php file. It wont store all its output in a variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
function execute($filename){
    include_once($filename);
    }
```

$filename is the name of your file to be included.. I think this will help you...

This is the function call..

```
 execute('abc.php');
```

Comment: this is no use buddy. @minitech gave answer which was i'm looking for. Anyways thanks your try in helping me :)